# MySQL Cursor Fetch not working

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have the following stored procedure that is meant to implement Dijkstra's shortest path algorithm:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `Dijkstras`(IN `pids` VARCHAR(512), IN `startP` VARCHAR(8), IN `endP` VARCHAR(8), OUT `dist` DECIMAL(20,10), OUT `eset` VARCHAR(1024))
BEGIN
DECLARE currentP VARCHAR(4);
DECLARE finished INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE pt_from, pt_to int;
DECLARE pt_dist decimal(20,10);
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;

DECLARE cur2 CURSOR FOR 
    select F.id as `from`, T.id as `to`, dist(F.lat, F.lng, T.lat, T.lng) 
      as dist
    from   sampledata F, sampledata T
    where  F.id < T.id and 
           find_in_set(convert(F.id, char(10)), pids) and
           find_in_set(convert(T.id, char(10)), pids) 
    order by dist;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR not found SET done = 1; 

    SET currentP= startP;
  SET eset = '';
  SET dist = 0;


  SET done=0;
  OPEN cur2; -- this finds pariwise distances in miles.
  REPEAT 
    FETCH cur2 INTO pt_from, pt_to, pt_dist; 
    SET dist= dist+pt_dist;
        SET eset= CONCAT(eset, ',');
    IF(currentP=pt_from OR currentP=pt_to) AND 
    (IN_SET(pt_from,pids) AND IN_SET(pt_to,pids))  THEN
        BEGIN
            SET dist= dist+ pt_dist;
            SET pids= REMOVE_MEMBER(currentP, pids);
            SET eset = concat(eset, ',', concat(pt_from, ':', pt_to));
                IF left(eset, 1) = ',' then 
                    SET eset = substring(eset, 2); -- remove extra comma.
                END IF;
            IF currentP=pt_from THEN
                SET currentP=pt_to;
            ELSE 
                SET currentP=pt_from; 
            END IF;
            IF currentP= endP THEN
            SET finished= 1;
            END IF;
     END;
      END IF;
         UNTIL done 

  END REPEAT; 
  CLOSE cur2;


END
```

My issue is that the cursor isn't working properly. When I fetch the current row into `pt_from, pt_to,` and `pt_dist` all I get are `NULL` values. The `sampledata` table is properly stored in the database and all the point ids in `pids` are also in the `sampledata` table. Plus this EXACT code works for another procedure, but reusing it here isn't working.

Anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The error was that I passed in the point ids like this `'12, 15, 18'` with spaces in between. MySQL counts the whitespace when it parses the strings, and the id's in the table were listed without spaces. The correct way to pass in the string set is `'12,15,18'`.